# Count number of results in text box in report higher than a certain number

Tags: ms-access, count, report

New to Access and i have built a basic database
We have inspections carried out and the results of the inspections are input into a form.
We score each area out of 30. I then added a calculation within the report in a text box which added up all the final scores and gave a total. which works fine.
Now what i want to do at the end of the report is that i want it to count the number of final scores that scored above and below 90 so i know which areas passed and failed.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Create a textbox in your report and use dCount("field_to_count", "Table_name", "field_to_count > 90)"

Comment: Hi thanks for reply. Trouble is my scoring in my report is within a table but the total score is a manual text box I have added within the report so it adds all scores in row .text box expression I have built is =[area]+ [area]+ [area] then the text box shows the total score - I want another text box in the report to count how many total scores score higher than 90

Comment: Understand....   I do not foresee how you can do it directly in the report. My suggestion is to create a query where you do the [area]+ [area]+ [area], and also the count, then use this query as the base for the report.